# What was the summer uniform of the streltsy?

Tags: military, russia, 17th-century, uniform

The Russian streltsy (shooters) of 17th century are usually depicted in winter uniform wearing fur hats and dress. What was their summer uniform?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Voted to close - trivia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the winter uniform, it's simply the uniform, and was worn in all weathers.

> In Russia in the early 17th century, strel’tsy (semiprofessional musketeers) wore red caftans (coats) with a white sash. In the second half of the 17th century, they wore fur-trimmed caftans of various colors, cloth caps, and colored high boots.
>
> ...
>
> Working and summer uniforms were introduced in 1718.
>
> -- [The Great Soviet Encyclopedia (1979)](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Military+Uniforms)

It's unclear if the summer uniforms were just for the navy, or for everyone, but this is the earliest date I can find for any mention of a winter or summer uniform, of any kind in any country. The Swedish 17th century Caroleans did not have separate winter and summer uniforms, for example.