# Why did the Streltsy in Russia have no summer uniform?

Tags: russia, 17th-century, uniform

As noted in [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/11477/332), the typical well-know-from-paintings red coats and hats uniform of Russian Streltsy guard was both a winter and summer uniform.

Is there any reason why an (obviously warm, to survive Russian winter) clothing was also used as summer uniform? It must have strongly reduced the military efficacy of the troops, who'd be sweltering in Moscow heat in summer in the same cloths required to survive Moscow winter.

Was it cost? Rarity of uniform clothing pre-textile-industry? Logistic issues? Or the fact that the uniform wasn't actually all that warm and winter warmth was instead achieved by layers of cloths worn under the red coats?

Comment: Please note that "Nobody else had summer uniforms then" isn't an asnswer - if that's your basis of approach, you need to explain why nobody else at the time introduced such an obvious military advantageous innovation.

Comment: 1. Loved the Russian Spetznaz line. 2. Can you give other examples of summer uniform from that time?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - I cannot (and possibly because there were none) - but please see my comment posted right while you were typing yours. P.S. I know that a bit earlier, in 1600s, in 30 year war they didn't really have uniforms per se in the first place.

Comment: Thick clothing also provides protection for various weapons.

Comment: Summer?! In _Russia_?! We have only winter here! Actually, two winters: the long one (with snow) and the the short one (without).

Comment: @sds - the one when people walk around in t-shirts and shorts

Comment: @LennartRegebro - valid consideration. E.f. Buff coats etc...

Comment: @LennartRegebro Good point. Cotton armor is also in the same class.

Comment: I hope they at least did not wear the fur hats in summer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, streltsy worn two types of kaftans – basic kaftan and kaftan for cold weather. Cold weather kaftan is quilted with sheepskin or fur and has fur collar and fur hem sleeves.

Basic kaftan:

[image: Basic kaftan]

Winter kaftan (note sleeves and collar):

[image: Winter kaftan]

According to Yuri Veremeev, ["Anatomy of Army"](http://army.armor.kiev.ua/forma-2/rus-forma-17v.shtml)

Comment: also, gloves...